# Пример связи "многие-ко-многим"

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте!
Не могу понять связь "многие ко многим".
Что она значит?
Приведите, пожалуйста, пример, когда эту связь нужно устанавливать.
Лучше даже пример из жизни приведите, пожалуйста, когда такая связь осуществляется.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Один-ко-многим" - тип связи таблиц, когда одной записи главной таблицы можно сопоставить несколько записей подчинённой таблицы. Это наиболее частый вид связи между таблицами.
Ну, например, если создавать телефонный справочник, то необходимо учесть, что у одного человека может быть несколько телефонов (2 мобильных, 1 домашний и 1 служебный). Или ещё пример: студент (записи о студентах хранятся в главной таблице) обучается в ВУЗе - он изучает несколько предметов (записи о предметах хранятся в подчинённой таблице), по которым сдаёт экзамены и зачёты.

А связь "многие-ко-многим" возникает в тех случаях, когда одной записи одной таблицы может соответствовать несколько записей другой таблицы и наоборот: когда одной записи второй таблицы может соответствовать несколько записей первой таблицы. От такого типа связи следует избавляться и приводить к виду "один-ко-многим". Пример такого вида связи: имеем 2 таблицы "Товары" и "Клиенты", каждый клиент может приобрести несколько товаров, в свою очередь каждый товар (по наименованию) может быть приобретён (или заказан) несколькими клиентами. Ещё пример (по ВУЗ): пусть есть 2 таблицы "Преподаватель" и "Студент", каждый преподаватель может обучать нескольких студентов, в то же время каждый студент может обучаться у нескольких преподавателей.

Comment: А, например, в Access как устанавливается подобная связь в схеме данных?

Comment: Почему "От такого типа связи следует избавляться"? Связь как связь.

Comment: Примеры, приведённые для связи "многие-ко-многим" хоть и верные по сути, ошибочны с точки зрения проектирования бд:) например, в примере про студентов - каждый студент состоит в группе, а преподаватель преподаёт предмет. У группы есть предметы, обратной связи никакой:) ну то есть по логике связи "многие ко многим" тут неоткуда взяться.

Answer (score 17):

К примеру есть у нас некий список людей:

**people**

`id | name | last_name`

и список книг

**books**

`id | name | author`

Что бы сохранить связь (кому какая книга нравится) нужна связь многие ко многим, которая реализуется посредством третьей таблици:

**people_book_like**

`people_id | book_id | liked_time`

---

Связь многие ко многим нужна для связи каких-то сущностей, которых может быть больше одной на сущность :) как то так, немного сумбурно, но я думаю вы поняли о чем я .

Answer (score 15):

Далеко ходить не будем и возьмем примеры из жизни:
Допустим создаем БД описывающее работу какой-то школы

1. Каждая школа гарантированно имеет 1-го директора. Это связь 1 к 1. 1 школа -> 1 директор
2. В каждой школе есть несколько классов это связь 1 ко многим. 1 школа -> много классов
3. Теперь учителя предметники. Если попробовать составить таблицу отношений учителей с классами то получим довольно сложную картину: 1 учитель может преподавать в нескольких классах, в то же самое время в одном классе может преподавать несколько учителей. Это и есть классическое отношение многие ко многим. Несколько учителей <-> Несколько классов.

Как уже было верно сказано выше такие связи принято описывать промежуточной таблицей связи