# Непонятная структура

Tags: mysql, sql

Товар, который может принадлежать нескольким категориям одновременно. Запросы: (1) достать все товары вместе с их категориями, (2) достать товар 'Огурец' вместе с его категориями, (3) достать все товары из категории 'Овощи', (4) достать все товары, которые принадлежат более чем одной категории

Сама структура

```
таблица product (продукт), поля: id, name (название), product_id (айди продукта)
таблица order (порядок), поля: id, product_id, category_id (айди категории)
таблица category (категория), поля: id, name (название),
```

Зачем у продукта, создавать поле айди продукта, если у него и так будет id?

Что означает таблица order? Почему она так названа?

У задач есть решения.

достать все товары вместе с их категориями:

```
SELECT * FROM product
LEFT JOIN order ON prdouct.category.id = order.id
LEFT JOIN category ON order.category_id = category.id
```

Вот эту цепочку

```
prdouct.category.id
```

я вообще не понимаю

Comment: Order - это скорее «заказ» а не порядок. Но “order” является зарезервированным словом в SQL, поэтому это плохое название для таблицы

Comment: Зачем у продукта, создавать поле айди продукта, если у него и так будет id?
Чаще всего такая структура используется для построения иерархической системы данных. 
prdouct.category.id - а это уже как-то сильно смахивает не на чистый sql, а на запросы из различных фреймворков, например JPA в java

Answer (score 1):

> Зачем у продукта, создавать поле айди продукта, если у него и так будет id?

Ну например product_id может вводиться вручную, содержать буквы и прочие не-цифры, или вообще импортироваться из другой системы. Он даже может быть неуникальным - синонимы никто не отменял.

> Что означает таблица order? Почему она так названа?

Таблица организует связь много-ко-много. А название, вероятно, взято с потолка - всё одно название ни на что не влияет.

> Вот эту цепочку
>
> ```
> prdouct.category.id
> ```
>
> я вообще не понимаю

Вероятно, `prdouct` - это наименование базы данных.

Comment: или должно быть так? prdouct.category_id

Comment: а может order это подкатегория?

Comment: Посмотри внимательно на этот `prdouct`. Там джойнится непонятно что

Answer (score 0):

> Зачем у продукта, создавать поле айди продукта, если у него и так будет id?

Вы правы, смысла нет. Скорее всего ошибка копипасты

> Что означает таблица order?

Обычная классическая кросс-таблица

> Почему она так названа?

Этот вопрос нужно задавать разработчику этой БД

> Вот эту цепочку
>
> ```
> prdouct.category.id
> ```
>
> я вообще не понимаю

Это бред. Спросите у того, кто писал этот запрос. Возможно `prdouct` это название БД, но тогда все равно запрос бессмысленный

А вообще для задачи

> достать все товары вместе с их категориями:

Решение такое

```
SELECT product.*, category.* FROM product
LEFT JOIN order ON order.product_id = product.id
LEFT JOIN category ON order.category_id = category.id
```

Comment: а может order это подкатегория?

Comment: @DivMan Если бы это было подкатегорией, то из нее не могло быть никаких ссылок на товар. Именно товар ссылался бы на нее. Но у нее нет даже названия. А по структуре - это типичный кросс

Comment: что значит типичный кросс?

Comment: что-то я вас не понимаю, почему, если бы это было подкатегорией, то нельзя было получить товар? Обычно так и делается

Comment: @DivMan https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/69750/221228

Answer (score 0):

> `prdouct.category.id`

Обычная опечатка. Похоже на `product.category_id`, но должно быть

```
LEFT JOIN order ON product.id = order.product_id
```

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, ok, не заметил просто.