# Mysql как лучше всего связать 2 таблицы если столбец имеет несколько значений

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, проектирование

**Таблица 1:**

```
id|title|actors
```

**Таблица 2:**

```
id|actor_id|actor_name
```

Первая таблица содержит список фильмов, вторая список актёров.
Естественно у фильма не может быть один актёр.

Как лучше всего связать таблицы, чтобы была возможность выборки по столбцу `actors`

**Мои варианты:**

1. Хранить id актёров через запятую в поле типа `SET` и выбирать через `FIND_IN_SET`.
2. Просто добавлять имена актёров через запятую. Убрать вторую таблицу (естественно таблица прибавит в весе так-как будет много повторов).
3. Ещё одна таблица со списком актёров которые снимались в конкретных фильмах (опять таки лишние записи в БД).

Есть ли варианты получше?

Comment: 3 вариант. Он единственный верный, если вы хотите использовать РСУБД как РСУБД, а не NoSQL хранилище. Прочтите про нормализацию базы данных. [Похожий на ваш вопрос и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/69743/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC)

Answer (score 0):

Так как в фильме может быть больше одного актера, а один актер за карьеру мог сняться больше чем в одном фильме, мы получаем связь многие-ко-многим. В РСУБД такая связь реализуется только через дополнительную таблицу с двумя столбцами-ссылками на связываемые сущности и ограничением на уникальность этой пары. Суррогатный ключ в данной таблице не нужен.

Comment: Актёр может сыграть в фильме более одной роли. Неизвестно, требуется ли эта информация, но если требуется, схема будет немного сложнее.

Comment: @Akina, Нет схема с более одной ролью не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Table1.title, * from Table2
 left join Table1 on Table1.actors like "%"+Table2.actor_name+"%"
```

Comment: @Suvitruf, Я так понимаю Вы имеете ввиду второй вариант?

Comment: @JohnDoe хм, ась?