# Записать массив в БД

Tags: php, sql

Не понимаю, как записать массив в БД. Нужно выбрать 3 тега максимум. Долго уже мучаюсь, ни к чему это так и не привело. Вот код:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
?>

<?php
$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$tags_id[] = $_POST['tags_id'];
$array = implode('; ', $tags_id);
var_dump($tags_id);

if (isset($_POST["discription"]))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO `quote` (`tags_id`, `author`, `discription`, `data`) VALUES ('$array', '{$_POST['author']}','{$_POST['discription']}','$data')";
    //$query = "INSERT INTO `quote` (`tags_id`, `author`, `discription`, `data`) VALUES ( '{$_POST['tags_id']}', '{$_POST['author']}', '{$_POST['discription']}', '$data')";
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    if ($sql)
    {
        echo '<h2>Данные добавлены!</h2>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<h2>Произошла ошибка. Данные не записаны.</h2>';
        echo $query;
    }                
}
?>

    <!-- Триггер/Открыть модальный -->
    <button id="myBtn">Открыть</button>
<form action="" method="post">
    <!-- Модальный -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Модальное содержание -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Создание цитаты</p>
        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Жанр:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="author"/>
        </div>
        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Цитата:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
            <textarea name="discription" class="form-control" id="shortdescription" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Теги:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">              
            <?php
            $sql = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT `id`, `Name` FROM `tags`');
            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                //echo "\t\t<option value=\"{$result['id']}\">{$result['Name']}</option>\n";
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='tags_id[]' id='tags_id' value=\"{$result['id']}\">{$result['Name']}  ,  ";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        </form> 
            <div><input type="submit" value="Сохранить" name="ok" class = "l"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Из этого всего возникает предупреждение:  Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\quotes\createquote.php on line 16

Линия 16: $array = implode('; ', $tags_id);

Если я делаю иначе - ошибка с попыткой записать массив. В общем. По итогу я пришла к тому, что выше. Но как все это исправить - понятия не имею.
var_dump($tags_id); - передает это: array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "4" } } и чего я делаю вывод, что данные выбранные он получает. Так что остается только преобразовать и записать в БД.

Если кто знает, как это сделать - была бы очень признательна!

Comment: `$tags_id = $_POST['tags_id'];`

Comment: Так-то оно так... но тогда добавляется только 1 значение, вот в чем проблема. А надо, чтоб добавлялось несколько.

И тогда при переходе на страницу меня встречают такие ошибки:
 Notice: Undefined index: tags_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\quotes\createquote.php on line 15 - $tags_id = $_POST['tags_id'];

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\quotes\createquote.php on line 16 - $array = implode('; ', $tags_id);

Comment: Какое такое одно значение?

Comment: Ну, первое, которое выбираю. Например, я выбираю 3 и 4, добавляется только 3

Comment: Само собой, тип колонки tags_id какой - int(11)? И как ты туда хочешь поместить несколько чисел?

Comment: опа. точняк. но как тогда мне следовало сделать? varchar? я все равно смогу сввязать ее с таблицей tags? картиночка: https://sun9-84.userapi.com/impg/74YdDkBY7p0mGjB8EHZhZeYufIark9MO0H5Smw/pptUDsnRzUY.jpg?size=739x283&quality=96&sign=85526662ef18c3f9c05f14855247bf38&type=album

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/69743/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC

Comment: Да.. на листике то оно и так многие ко многим. я забыла про пром таблицы в таком случае. господи. я на самом деле понятия не имею какую пром таблицу делать. ладно. сейчас думать буду. спасибо большое!