# SQL связь многие ко многим

Tags: mysql

2 таблицы "Авторы" и "Книги"
в таблице книги такие поля, как название книги, изображение обложки, краткое описание, год выпуска и автор(ы), жанр книги
Одна книга может быть написана несколькими авторами и один автор может написать несколько книг.
без понятия как это делать, со связью многие ко многим работаю в первый раз

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Пример связи "многие-ко-многим"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/69743/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bc)